# MouseClickEvent if Input empty, show Messagebox before continuing

Tags: powershell, messagebox, mouseclick-event

I am struggling with a Messagebox within a ClickEvent in a Form.

An InputBox expects some text entered. If that is not the case, a MessageBox shall PopUp and Inform, that No Text has been entered. That does work but then I am stuck in the loop itself.

I tried the following:

```
NextButtonClickevent = {

    Do {
    If (!$InputBox.Text){[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('No Answer Entered','Ooops','OK','Warning')}

    }
    Until ($InputBox.Text -ne '')
```

The problem with the do until loop is, that as soon as the OK button of the Messagebox is clicked, the messagebox will re-appear before giving me a chance to enter some text.

What do I have to do, so I can loop until I have entered something and then it will continue within the ClickEvent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `Do..Until` loop with this:

```
If (!$InputBox.Text){
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('No Answer Entered','Ooops','OK','Warning')
    Return $False
}
```

Comment: Hello Rich, I just tried, and for some reason, it does not like "False" The error says, The term 'False' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file... did I make a mistake?

Comment: Apologies - I fixed the typo `False` -> `$False`. Please try the updated code.

Comment: Sorry my bad, the $ somehow disappeared. Now it is working perfectly, thanx Rich